# How can I make my question better?

Tags: support, specific-question, asking-questions

I asked a question a yesterday and haven't seen much activity for a while. I am really struggling to properly formulate my question. Is there any way I can improve this post? Should I make a new question, asking more broadly how to model infinite helixes?

[Stokes theorem question: finding the right modeling approach and choosing between polar and cartesian coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2202994/stokes-theorem-question-finding-the-right-modeling-approach-and-choosing-betwee)